# Gradle task to generate Android manifest

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

In my Android project `AndroidManifest.xml` needs to be built from other files. I wrote a task called `generateManifest`.

What should I specify in my Gradle build script to make sure that `generateManifest` is executed before `AndroidManifest.xml` is accessed by the other Android tasks? In other words, what Android plugin tasks should I configure as `.dependsOn generateManifest` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
preBuild.dependsOn generateManifest
```

Plus the less obvious:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'your.app.id'
    }
}
```

Without it, the Android plugin during its initialization will try to read the package id from the (non-existing) manifest.